# Apache server and a Microsoft CA

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, openssl

I've been trying to add SSL to a vTiger 6 CRM server for the past couple of days. My IT director and I have been trying to figure this out...

We have followed this guide to create our certs
https://secure.marumoto.us/motowiki/tiki-index.php?page=Use+a+Microsoft+CA+to+Sign+a+Certificate+for+a+Web+Server

I've moved the certs over to the server and enabled SSL.

When I connect to the server with Firefox and download the certification, its not filling in the certification fields correctly. Its showing the Issued By fields as the webserver it self... not our Microsoft CA server.

My httpd.conf file looks like...

```
Servername herpderp.derp.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/herpderp.derp.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/herpderp.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/tower.derp.com.pem
```

What could be the problem? I've been pouring through documentation for a day now..

Comment: So the certificate being presented by the web server is self signed, instead of being issued by your Windows CA, correct?  What steps did you take to create this certificate?

Comment: Yep that's whats going on Shane...

Comment: I followed that guide I posted word for word

Comment: Can you provide the output (sanitized if needed) of `openssl x509 -in /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/tower.derp.com.pem -noout -text`?

Comment: I've actually discovered whats going on... ssl.conf is overwriting what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using a VirtualHost, so the settings in ssl.conf were being applied. I changed the values in ssl.conf to the following, and got the cert working correctly.

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/herpderp.derp.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/herpderp.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.cert/tower.derp.com.pem